# Navigating without onPress click in react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

My app is navigating directly to the login screen when clicked on the review button from a listing detail screen but it should only navigate when clicked on 'Post a review' button on the review screen. I have also applied a condition if the user is login to the system then only he can post a review else when clicked on post a review button on the review screen he should be redirected to the login screen.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    ScrollView,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Modal,
    TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import { Button, Paragraph, Wrapper } from '../components';
import { baseStyle, images, theme, routes } from '../config';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext';



export const Reviews = ({ route }) => {
    const { userInfo } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const navigation = useNavigation();


    const [isModalVisible, setisModalVisible] = useState(false);
    const { item } = route.params;
    const [responseData, setResponseData] = React.useState();
    const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
    const [text, setText] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = async () => {
        console.log('Submitted Feedback: ', text);
        await axios.post(`https://17f4-119-157-85-76.ngrok-free.app/listing/${item.id}/feedback`, {
            feedback: text, token: userInfo.data
        }).then(res => {
            let FeedbackInfo = res.data;
            // setFeedbackinfo(FeedbackInfo);
            // AsyncStorage.setItem('FeedbackInfo', JSON.stringify(FeedbackInfo));
            console.log(FeedbackInfo);

        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(`feedback error ${e}`);
        });
        setisModalVisible(!isModalVisible);

    }


        React.useEffect(async () => {
            await axios.get(`https://17f4-119-157-85-76.ngrok-free.app/listing/${item.id}/feedback`)
                .then(response => {
                    setResponseData(response.data.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }, [item]);





    // const saveFeedback = async()=>{
    //     const url = `https://903f-202-47-60-211.ngrok-free.app/listing/${item.id}/feedback`;
    //     let result = await fetch(url, {
    //         method: "POST",
    //         headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    //         body: JSON.stringify({
    //             feedback: inputText, token: userInfo.data
    //         })
    //     });
    //     result = await result.json();
    //     console.log(result);
    // } 
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <View style={styles.header} >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                    <Image source={images.back} style={styles.backIcon} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                < Text style={styles.headerText} > Reviews </Text>
            </View>
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.review} >
                {console.log(responseData)}
                {responseData &&
                    responseData.length > 0
                    ?
                    responseData.map((item) => (
                        <View style={styles.reviewContainer}>
                            <View style={styles.flex} >
                                <Paragraph style={styles.reviewer} > {item.name} </Paragraph>
                            </View>
                            <Paragraph>
                                {item.feedback_desc}
                            </Paragraph>
                        </View>
                    ))
                    :
                    null
                }
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.footer} >
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Button onPress={userInfo.data
                        ?
                        (() => setisModalVisible(true))
                        :
                        navigation.navigate(routes.LOGIN, { item: item })}> Post a review </Button>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <Modal
                transparent={true}
                animationType='slide'
                visible={isModalVisible}
            >
                <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={{ height: 40 }}
                        placeholder="Type here to translate!"
                        onChangeText={newText => setText(newText)}
                        value={text}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.Button}>
                        <Button onPress={() => handleSubmit()}> Submit </Button>
                        <Button onPress={() => setisModalVisible(false)}> Close </Button>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </Wrapper >
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you are calling the navigation directly inside onPress, you have to pass a function and when you click on it it will run.

```
<View style={styles.footer}>
  <Button
    onPress={() => {
      if (userInfo.data) setisModalVisible(true);
      else navigation.navigate(routes.LOGIN, { item: item });
    }}
  >
    Post a review
  </Button>
</View>
```